# How to remove the &nbsp in beginning and end of the html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an HTML content with `&nbsp;` I want to remove `&nbsp;` from the beginning and end of the content. No need to remove in-between.

I tried by using this:

```
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\&nbsp;/g, '');
```

el have some HTML contents. When used like this, in-between `&nbsp;` also gets removed.

My HTML content should like below

[image]

How to remove `&nbsp;` from HTML content at the beginning and end?

Example:  If HTML content should like `<p>&nbsp;test&nbsp;example&nbsp;</p>` means, I want output like `<p>test&nbsp;example</p>`.

Comment: Can not understand your question. Example code will make your question clear. I think you need to make margin, and padding to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The trim from jQuery is what you are looking for.

```
$.trim('  string with spaces at the ends   ');
```

Or plain javascript:

```
'  string with spaces at the ends   '.trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, no jQuery required. This will trim standard spaces and fixed  
NOTE: you might need to change to recursive or looped if there are multiple spaces.

EDIT: Changed code to manage for element based content also.

```js
let samples = [
  '&nbsp;<p>test&nbsp;</p>&nbsp;',
  ' <p>test</p> ',
  '<p>&nbsp;test&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>',
  '<p class="test">&nbsp;test&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>'
];

/**
* This function is checking to see if the value is wrapped in an HTML Element
* @param str the string you wish to test. 
*/
const isElementBased = (str) => {
  // Test to see if the content is wrapped in an element
  let pattern = /^<[\S\s]+?>.+?<\/[\S\s]+?>$/;
  return str.match(pattern);
}

/**
* This function will remove leading and trailing spaces/token
* @param str the string to be checked and have replacement action
* @param tokenOverride optional ability to override the seach token.
*/
const removeFixedSpaces = (str, tokenOverride) => {  
  let token = (tokenOverride === undefined) ? '&nbsp;' : tokenOverride;
  str = str.trim();
  if (str.startsWith(token)) {
    str = str.substring(token.length);
  }
  if (str.endsWith(token)) {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - token.length);
  }
  return str;
}

const remove = (str) => {
  let container;
  if(isElementBased(str)) {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    container.innerHTML = str;
    str = container.firstChild.innerHTML;
  }
  
  str = removeFixedSpaces(str);
  
  if(container) {
    container.childNodes[0].innerHTML = str;
    str = container.innerHTML;
  }
  
  return str;  
}

samples.forEach(s => {
  console.log(`Testing: ${s}`);
  console.log(`Result : ${remove(s)}`);
});
```

Comment: I like your usage of the let and lambda syntax! But on the one side your function does more than needed (trim and remove &nbsp;) and on the other side it is only good to remove &nbsp; - I think it would be better to have a more generic approach like giving the "&nbsp;" as a parameter to the function. +1 from me!

Comment: @Bibberty My HTML content should like `<p>&nbsp;test&nbsp;example&nbsp;</p>` I want output like `<p>test&nbsp;example</p>`.

Comment: Ok, to be clear. Are you wanting just the first. Or all spaces until a word?

Comment: I want to remove the space at the front and back of the word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array operations like `split()`, `pop()`, `splice()` and `join()`:

```js
let elText = '&nbsp;<p>test&nbsp;</p>&nbsp;';
elText = elText.split('&nbsp;')
//remove last &nbsp;
elText.pop();
//remove first &nbsp;
elText.splice(0,1);
elText = elText.join('&nbsp;');
console.log(elText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex is a bit like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut.
I would do something simple like this:

```
const trim = (text, find) => {
    let beginPos = 0;
    let endPos = text.length;

    while (text.substring(beginPos, beginPos+find.length) == find)
    {
        beginPos += find.length;
    }
    while (text.substring(endPos-find.length, endPos) == find)
    {
        endPos -= find.length;
    }
    return text.substring(beginPos, endPos);
}
// Usage: trim("Your Text", "&bnsp;")
```

This removes ALL occurrences of whatever you want from begin and end... it sould be self-explanatory.

Comment: You can easily modify this to provide a left-trim, right-trim and create a trim that uses the left- and right trim implementation. Further you can modify the code to only remove the first occurence (or use a parameter to decide what to do if you like).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following regex:

```
el.innerHTML.trim().replace(/^&nbsp;(.*)&nbsp;$/g, '$1')
```

1. `trim` first to remove all trailing whitespaces.
2. capture everything between the first and last `&nbsp;`